# what is the actual return type for LocalDate.now().toString()

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to save `LocalDateTime` to DB. So my scenario is I have consumer and producer. Producer generated some code and gives it to consumer, and consumer saves the entries to database.

Code on Producer Side

```
LocalDate.now().toString() // returns 2021-07-13T12:25:38.841775700 sometimes it returns 2021-07-13T12:25:38.841 so basically after the last decimal point the precision can be anything.
```

Code on Consumer side

On the consumer side i want to save entries from received from producer into the db for that i need to convert the str to LocalDateDime.

```
  private static DateTimeFormatter timeFormatterInMs= DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

  public static LocalDateTime unmarshalDateTime(final String dateTimeStr) {
    return dateTimeStr == null ? null : LocalDateTime.parse(str, timeFormatterInMs);
  }
```

Here the problem is what is the format for return type of LocalDateTime

i know it return data in the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` by in our case ms have sometimes 9, sometimes 6  decimal places? if i will give this string to the function unmarshalDateTime(..) the function will break and it wont work properly. because it expects the ms part to be 3 decimal places. what to do about it

Comment: So your producer takes a perfectly good `LocalDate` and then call `toString` on it - returning whatever the default human readable form is. You then are having trouble parsing that _back to a `LocalDate`_? Can you think of a simpler approach that perhaps skips that issue entirely?

Comment: But to answer your actual question it’s [ISO-8601](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--). But as above, don’t turn things into strings to parse them again.

Comment: I think you meant `LocalDateTime.now().toString()`. `LocalDate` cannot produce any string like the ones you are mentioning.

Comment: Excuse my curiosity, you got 4 answers to your question, were any of them helpful? Is there anything that you are still missing?

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question is in the documentation of `LocalDateTime.toString()` (link at the bottom):

> Outputs this date-time as a String, such as `2007-12-03T10:15:30`.
>
> The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:
>
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm`
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS`
>
> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of
> the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.

To parse such a string back into a `LocalDateTime` don’t use any formatter at all. The one-arg `LocalDateTime.parse(CharSequence)` parses every one of those formats.

Let me show you:

```
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2021-07-13T12:25:38.841775700"));
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2021-07-13T12:25:38.841"));
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2021-07-13T12:26"));
```

Output:

> ```
> 2021-07-13T12:25:38.841775700
> 2021-07-13T12:25:38.841
> 2021-07-13T12:26
> ```

This said Ali Behzadian Nejad is correct in his answer: assuming that those values are supposed to define points in time, `LocalDateTime` is the wrong type for them. Use `Instant`. If you can, use `timestamp with time zone` on the SQL side. Depending on your JDBC driver you may or may not need to convert via `OffsetDateTime`. If you need to store strings, `Instant.toString()` too can produce different formats and can parse each and every one of them back through the one-arg `Instant.parse()`.

### Documentation links

- [`LocalDateTime.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString())
- [`LocalDateTime.parse(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence))

Answer (score 1):

Storing local dates in database is not a good idea because they are not instants of time, they are just localized presentation of time.

Create an `Instant` object from LocalTime and its timezone and save that time `Instant` in database column with `Timestamp` type:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = ...
Instant instant = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")).toInstant();
```

From Java documentation:

> This class [LocalDateTime] does not store or represent a time-zone.
> Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays,
> combined with the local time as seen on a wall clock. It cannot
> represent an instant on the time-line without additional information
> such as an offset or time-zone.

Answer (score 0):

With jdk11: [The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString())
Also there have LocalDate.format to generate a time string by format.

BTW, if you want save time to database I suggest use `long` or `Timestamp` instead of `String`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `DateTimeFormatter` that considers different patterns in order to parse `String`s with different amounts of fractions-of-second (here: 6 or 9):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String datetime = "2021-07-13T12:25:38.841775700";
    String datetimeShort = "2021-07-13T12:25:38.841775";
    // provide a formatter that "knows" two different patterns
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "[uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnn][uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS]");
    // parse the one with 9 fractions-of-second
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, dtf);
    // and the one with 6 using the same formatter
    LocalDateTime ldtShort = LocalDateTime.parse(datetimeShort, dtf);
    // output the parsed LocalDateTimes
    System.out.println(ldt + " and " + ldtShort + " are successfully parsed");
}
```

This outputs

```
2021-07-13T12:25:38.841775700 and 2021-07-13T12:25:38.841775 are successfully parsed
```

Comment: this will work. i have two doubts:
1. what is SSSSSS and nnnnnnnnn. does S stands for milliseconds or microseconds. does n stands for nanoseconds
2. i actually dont know after decimal how many digits will be there. in your example you have assumed that after decimal either six or nine decimal points will be there. but what if 3 digits are there after decimal points. in that case it will break right

Comment: I think so, you have to cover all the possible options. Best practice would be to use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` in order to handle arbitrary amounts of fractions-of-second. According to [the JavaDocs of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), `S` is *fraction-of-second* and `n` is *nano-of-second*. This will work with 9 `S` instead of 9 `n`s, too.

Comment: You need no formatters at all. The one-arg `LocalDateTime.parse()` parses all variants that `LocalDateTime.toString()` can produce, from `2021-07-14T20:18` (no seconds) up to `2021-07-14T20:18:56.284650926` (seconds and 9 decimals on the seconds).